# Правильная команда Curl для загрузки локального файла по URL-адресу

Tags: php, curl

У меня есть PHP код:

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/local/file';
$cFile = curl_file_create($path);
$token = '0123456789';
$post = array('token' => $token, 'file' => $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.myfiles.com/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
if(isset($result['status']) && $result['status'] === 'success') {
echo $result['url'];
} else {
echo $result['message'];
}
?>
```

Можно ли с помощью curl организовать выгрузку файлов на сервер?
Я попытался сделать это так, но не выходит:

```
curl https://api.myfiles.com/upload -H 'Authorization: 0123456789' -F "file=@c:\myfiles\file.pdf"
```

Мне нужно использовать curl в bat файле из под Windows и **важно, чтобы команда curl размещалась в одной строке**. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: в php скрипте вы токен кидаете в POST данные, а в curl в заголовках.  В чём важность команды в одну строку тоже не ясно. Можно переносить длинные команды на несколько строк

Comment: На самом деле я использую curl -X POST но все равно это не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте поиск по сайту
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files>